# Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem returns GETFILESTATUS failed with Unknown Error for valid items

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to setup a new Data Lake store gen1 account, and create folders with updated ACLs. The New-AzDataLakeStoreAccount statement works fine; New-AzDataLakeStoreItem and Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem fail with similar Unknown Error.

Following powershell code will create a new Data Lake store. I have a resourcegroup and security group in the subscription as listed below. The second and third scripts for listing and adding a folder fail. I'm using https://shell.azure.com to execute the powershell.

```
New-AzDataLakeStoreAccount -ResourceGroupName "ade-dev-eastus2" -Name "adedeveastus2" -Location "East US 2" -DefaultGroup (Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName "Technical Operations").Id -Encryption ServiceManaged -Tag @{User="ADE";}-Tier Consumption

Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "adedeveastus2" -Path "/"

New-AzDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "adedeveastus2" -Path "/Staging" -Folder
```

Following is an error message for Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem

> Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem : Error in getting metadata for path /.
>   Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with   Unknown Error: Token Length is 6. Token is most probably malformed. Source:  StackTrace: .
>   Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries. [There was an error retrieving the managed service access token for resource 'https://datalake.azure.net' using the URI 'http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fdatalake.azure.net&api-version=2018-02-01'.  Please check that this managed service is configured to emit tokens at this address and that the associated managed service identity has the appropriate role assignment and try logging in again.,Token Length is 6. Token is most probably malformed.,Token Length is 6. Token is most probably malformed.,Token Length is 6. Token is most probably malformed.,Token Length is 6. Token is most probably malformed.]
>   [ServerRequestId:]
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem -Account "adedeveastus2" -Path "/"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem], AdlsException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.GetAzureDataLakeStoreItem

The error returned when using a Windows Powershell host is more descriptive.

> Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with Unknown Error: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

I would expect to get back a DataLakeStoreItem object, and things like Name and Path. I think a general error for other users of ADL or the Cloud shell powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in the Azure Cloud Shell, when I run the command in local(`PSVersion is 5.1.17134.228`), I got the same error with the [GitHub known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8141).

As the datalake team said, see this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8141#issuecomment-447525703):

> This is a problem with Httpwebrequest class used by our SDK. Setting useragent for httpwebrequest is different across netframework and netcore:
>
> NET framework: `webReq.UserAgent = client.GetUserAgent()`
>
> net standard: `webReq.Headers["User-Agent"] = client.GetUserAgent()`
>
> If you try to later thing in net framework you get the error you are getting above.
>
> When you use this az module which is using the netstandard dll of our SDK. When you use that from windows powershell, its trying to use net standard dll on netframework which gives this error.

And the **soluation**:

> I tested this in net core powershell. It runs fine.
>   We are moving from httpwebrequest to httpclient which will probably fix the issue.
>
> So basically if you are using windows powershell use azurerm or else use Az from powershell netcore.

It seems explains the error `The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method`, so you could try to use the `Az` powershell in [Powershell core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6). If it is acceptable, you can also use [`AzureRM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) powershell module in windows powershell, it works fine on my side.

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "joydatalake2" -Path "/"
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "joydatalake2" -Path "/Staging" -Folder
```

[image]